# How to create multibyte characters in C

Tags: c++, c, encoding, character, multibyte

During my study of character encoding in C and C++ I came across two general ways of encoding: multibyte characters and wide characters. In order to strengthen my understanding of those systems (benefits and drawbacks) I wanted to do some examples.
Doing examples with wide characters is not a problem due to the native support with the wchar_t type. But when I wanted to create a string which contains those so called multibyte characters I came to a problem.

How can I actually create a multibyte character string which uses an encoding that works with a char array (using Visual C++)? This kind of encoding sure does exist: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Shift-State.html. But I read only about it and never saw an actual example. Or do you have to create your own encoding for this kind of string?

Comment: in qt there is the tr function which handles the differences in the compilers with multibyte strings. All you need to do is encode your source file in utf-8 and call tr with the string literals.

Comment: Do you mean sth. like `"\xc3\x84"`? (this is the german "Ä" UTF-8 coded)

Comment: @DavidFeurle I don't think that's correct, `tr()` is there for i18n (translations).

Comment: It is indeed a quiet mess with terms in the field of string encoding. Sure, UTF-8 is also a multibyte character encoding. But I was not necessarily referring to Unicode Formats but rather to multibyte formats which can be represented with the char type. There are various ways to encode a string with an array of char instead of wchar_t. One example uses the concept of so called shift states: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Shift-State.html. I am actually searching for a way on how to encode a multibyte character string with an array of type char.

Comment: @Angew you are right - tr does some more but it calls QString::fromUtf8 which handles string handling in different compilers and "just works" with utf8 encoded source files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to create a wide character string literal, simply omitting the L should give you a multibyte character string literal with an implementation defined encoding (gcc has an option to chose it, I don't know about visual C++).

If you have a wide character string, you can get the equivalent multibyte string according to the C locale using the functions `wcstombs` (in `<stdlib.h>`) and `wcsrtombs` (in `<wchar.h>`).

C++ locale system also provides a way to do that conversion.  (Look for the `in` and `out` member of the `codecvt` facet, I won't provide here a tutorial on their use, the site cppreference has example codes, for instance for [out](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt/out)).

I'm not sure you'll be able to find easily support either on Unix or on Windows for an encoding with a shift state.  You should search for encoding for China, Japan, Korea, Vietman (for instance [ISO 2022-JP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022), but it seems to me that Unix tend to use [EUC-JP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code#EUC-JP) instead and Windows [Shift JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS)).